upgrading react-native to 0.74.1
I'm trying to run an app with expo and it started showing me this error about ViewPropTypes problem, so I decided to upgrade react-native to latest to check if the error goes, the last error disappeared but now I got this error that I haven't even found anything related to it in the entire internet

node_modules\react-native\src\private\specs\components\DebuggingOverlayNativeComponent.js:
C:\Projects\name\node_modules\react-native\src\private\specs\components\DebuggingOverlayNativeComponent.js:
Unsupported param type for method "highlightTraceUpdates", param
"updates". Found $ReadOnlyArray

I ended up doing yarn upgrade to the entire app, but the error persists. How to solve it?

have you found a solution? I got this same error when trying to use pnpm instead of yarn

I just ran into this as well. Checked the RN github issues, and found this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/43678#issuecomment-2023948847
Updating @react-native/babel-preset fixed it for me. Or more specifically in my case, babel-preset-expo since I'm using expo. I was running 10.0.1 and upgraded to 11.0.5. Back up and running.

Installing babel-preset-expo didn't fix it for me, deleting the yarn.lock did.
I ran expo-doctor and it gave me errors on outdated packages that wasn't part of my package.json, I deleted yarn.lock, node_modules, android, and ios, ran yarn install and npx expo prebuild then rebuild the project and that seems to fixed it.

It was still probably the babel-preset-expo change that fixed it. The outdated packages error is a different error from the one you were getting, right? So that means you just didn't update the project after updating the package...

Actually I kept getting the same error, but you may be correct.

In my case, I was using an incompatible SDK version with my current React native version. I only updated the SDK version, and that fixed the problem
